# Inequailities on conditional entropy of a markov chain

Tags: inequality, markov-chains, information-theory, entropy

Let $x_{n}$ a stationary discrete markov chain . I have to prove that:

For $n\geq 1$
$$ H(X_{n} | X_{0}) \geq H(X_{n-1} | X_{0})$$
$$ H(X_{0} | X_{n}) \geq H(X_{0} | X_{n-1})$$

Where $H(X)$ is the Shannon entropy.

The second inequality seems to me that is a corollary of the first one because if
$$X_{1} \rightarrow X_{2}  \rightarrow X_{3} \rightarrow ...$$
Then

$$X_{1} \leftarrow X_{2}  \leftarrow X_{3} \leftarrow ... $$
(I am not completely sure).

But why do I have as hyphotesis the stationary distribution?

Maybe you can help me with this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just apply the data processing inequality:

$$I(X_0; X_{n-1})\ge I(X_0; X_n)$$

Equivalently

$$H(X_{n-1}) - H(X_{n-1}|X_0) \ge H(X_n) - H(X_n | X_0)$$

As $X$ is stationary, $X_n$ and $X_{n-1}$ have the same distribution, hence $H(X_n)=H(X_{n-1})$, and the first inequality follows.

For the second one, what is $X$? Anyway, it should follow in a similar manner...

The stationary hypothesis cannot be omitted:

Let the process be that there are only two states $\{0, 1\}$. In state $0$, it stays $0$ with a $\frac{1}{2}$ probability, and in state $1$, it stays $1$ with probability $1$. Let $X_0=0$ with certainty (so $H(X|X_0)=H(X)$ for any $X$), it's clear that $X_1$ has entropy $1$. As time goes by, the probability of $X$ being $0$ is diminishing, hence the entropy is decreasing instead of increasing.

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align}
H(X_n|X_0) &\ge H(X_n |X_{1}, X_0) &\text{(conditioning reduces entropy)} \\
&= H(X_n|X_1) &\text{($X_0\to X_1 \to X_n$ is Markov)} \\
&= H(X_{n-1}|X_0) &\text{(the sequence is stationary)}\\
\end{align}$$

Indeed, stationarity is not required for $H(X_n|X_0) \implies H(X_n|X_1)$, but is required for the last step. Furthermore, the chain must be stationary not only in the sense that the transition probabilities are constant, but also that $X_0$ has already the  stationary distribution.